# How can I listen to keyboard events in all controls of a Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, keyboard, keydown

I have to listen to keyboard event in my Window, but if I use this code:

```
 MyWindow.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MainWindow_KeyDown);
```

I don't get events fired inside other controls, like textbox. How can I get events from ALL controls and stop the propagation of the event to its original control?

**EDIT**

I tried this code:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Window.KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(MainWindow_KeyDown));
```

I works for most case, but for example it did not get the HOME key when I'm inside a textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have look into [PreviewKeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
this.PreviewKeyDown += MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown;
```

Event handler:

```
private void MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     // do some stuff
     e.Handled = true // Stops propagating the event
}
```

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you,